# How can I set the first day of the week to monday in dojox.calendar (columnview)

Tags: date, dojo

How can I set the first day of the week to monday in dojox.calendar (columnview)?

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/calendar.html

In the documentation it says there is a startDate property in the columnView,
but you have to set a date. How can I set the startDate on Monday?

If I set a startDate, nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

startDate * - The date of the first column,
Properties with an (*) are computed by the calendar widget.

The calendar renders the startdate from the locale of the browser.